# Cms block custom field

Tags: magento-1, cms, cms-block

i add Mobile Status below is my code for cms block section it show out form section and i want to move it after status dropdown

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('cms_block');
    $form = parent::_prepareForm()->getForm();
    // $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fieldset_cms', 
    array('legend'=>Mage::helper('core')->__('Mobile')));
        $form->addField('is_active_mobile', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active_mobile',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
            'value'     => $model->getIsActiveMobile(),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
            'required'  => true,
            'options'   => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('No'),
            ),
     ));
     return $this;    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('cms_block');
    $form = parent::_prepareForm()->getForm();
    $elem = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
    $elem->addField('is_active_mobile', 'select', array(
        'name'      => 'is_active_mobile',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
        'value'     => $model->getIsActiveMobile(),
        'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
        'required'  => true,
        'options'   => array(
            '1' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Yes'),
            '0' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('No'),
        ),
    ), 'is_active');

    return $this;

}
```

Comment: great now how move after status

Comment: Check updated answer